# VS 2015 Web Compiler won't auto-compile .less files on save

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-compiler

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 and, since Web Essentials won't compile `.less` files anymore, I installed the Web Compiler add-on for compiling `.less` files.

The issue is that I can't seem to set it up to auto-compile the `.less` file into `.css` on save. What can be done for compiling the `.less` files on save?

Answer (score 9):

I use **Web Essentials** with **Visual Studio 2015** when using **Less**. Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2013 has the  built-in feature that compiled your **.less** file into a **.css** and **.min.css** file, and it also had the feature to update the .css and .min.css files when you save your .less file.

Now with VS 2015, I had to download two seperate add-ons to get this feature back:
[Web Compiler](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c) and [Bundler & Minifier](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40)

I thought my Visual Studio/Web Essentials add-on was broken... Bundler & Minifier should fixed the auto-save issue for you, it did for me :)

Comment: I had Web Essentials and Bundler & Minifier installed and still had the problem. Installing the Web Compiler add-on as well seems to be mandatory.

Comment: You might find that even after installing Web Compiler it doesn't compile on save. If so, delete the `%localappdata%\temp\WebCompler???` folder. Sometimes you need to restart VS, sometimes you don't. Doesn't work for everyone, but seems to work for a lot of people

Comment: check for errors in your .less files also (not always clear)  .less file with errors will not generate css file.

Answer (score 0):

now with VisualStudio 2015 you have to use a task manager like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). These  tools are NPM packages which can be executed in visual studio with the "task runner explorer"

By example, try to implement (with the complete tutorials on my links) Gulp with the "gulp-less" module to compile your less files, then you can attach your gulp execution with some events of Visual Studio ( like pre-build, post-build .. etc ) or you can use "**gulp-watch**" to check when you save a less file and automatically compile them.

Comment: thanks for the answer - from where do I download gulp-watch?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch here is the documentation, but i'm not sure if Gulp will install it for you if you write your gulpfile.js with : 
var lessCompile = require("gulp-less");